# Spring Boot @Valid doesn't display message from @NotBlank

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, validation, post

Why message from @NotBlank is not displayed?

Controller API:

```java
@PostMapping("/create-folder")
public SuccessResponse createFolder(Principal principal, @Valid @RequestBody CreateFolderRequest request) {
    return historyService.createFolder(principal.getName(), request.getFolderName());
}
```

Request Body:

```java
@Data
public class CreateFolderRequest {
    @NotBlank(message = "Folder name is mandatory.")
    private String folderName;
}
```

JSON Response:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-18T11:24:19.769+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Validation failed for object='createFolderRequest'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/api/history/create-folder"
}
```

Packages:
Valid:
`import javax.validation.Valid;`
NotBlank:
`import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;`

There is no global exception handlers in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Valid throw an exception of MethodArgumentNotValidException you massege in @NotBlank is get throw inside exception detail which isn't return to the customer. you need to extract the messages so try adding this method to the controller.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return errors;
    }
```

above code read all errors inside the exception then get thier detail (filedName - errorMessage) and put them in list and then return the list to the clinet with 400 bad request status